# Explorer Wont Release Files After Using My Thumbnail Provider

Tags: c#, .net, thumbnails

I've set up a thumbnail provider for a file type.

The project is made with

- C#
- .NET 4.5

And I am running Windows x64

My provider successfully generates the thumbnail as expected and I can move, delete, copy, ect, the file. The issue of the locking seems to be caused by the file being placed in a folder. At that point, moving, deleting, ect, the folder all show the error, "File In Use".

I have confirmed Explore locking the file using Sysinternal's Process Explorer, if you are familiar with it.

I've tried 2 approaches to try to resolve this...

1. implemented `IThumbnailProvider` and `IInitializeWithStream` myself.
2. used 3rd party [Sharpshell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563114/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Thumbnail-Handlers)

Both suffer from this same issue, the file not being released.

On Sharpshell's github, an issue has been started specifying this too.
https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/issues/78

I associate the file type in the registry like so

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
---- .qb
      ----shellex
          ----{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96} : my CLSID...
```

I have also tried instead...

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
---- .qb
     -----PersistentHandler : my CLSID...
```

Both result in this issue being created.

If I was to implement `IExtractImage` instead... will I see the same issue?

I know C# isn't "officially" supported to do this, is that where my issue lies? If I was to implement this in C++ would I wind up with the same issue?

**EDIT:**

I'd like to mention the file after around 1 minute seems to get freed, and things go back to normal.

**Thumbnail Creation**

Some bytes are read into a buffer... then then image is generated from that.

```
public void GetThumbnail(int cx, out IntPtr hBitmap, out WTS_ALPHATYPE   bitmapType)
{
    ... bunch of other code
    using (MemoryStream steam = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    using (var image = new Bitmap(steam))
    using (var scaled = new Bitmap(image, cx, cx))
    {
        hBitmap = scaled.GetHbitmap();
        hBitmap = (IntPtr)(hBitmap.ToInt64());
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Doing some more testing, I called DeleteObject(hBitmap), (even though this destroys the thumbnail), and the file is still locked. I even removed all the code from `GetThumbnail`... just gives the same result, file locked. There has to be something more going on?

Comment: Can you post a code sample showing the code which saves the thumbnail file?  Sounds like an object needs to be cleanly disposed of.

Comment: @JohnBevan if scaled.GetHbitmap(); is the problem how would I dispose of it.. and not loose the image for the thumbnail.

Comment: Two words: Garbage collection.

Comment: [You are responsible for calling the GDI DeleteObject method to free the memory used by the GDI bitmap object.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @RaymondChen you are referring to the GetHbitmap() call then. I am aware MS says we are to dispose of the resource ourselves. How do I do so without loosing the image I've created... (I've called DeleteObject(hBitmap) before which results in the thumbnail not showing up)

Comment: No, that wouldn't explain why the file is not closed. It's because " [Nondeterministic finalization can conflict with some interface contracts. For example, thumbnail handlers are required to release all resources immediately when their reference count drops to zero.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to release the COM IStream object that you get from `IInitializeWithStream`.

I came to this conclusion by reading more about disposing COM objects.

[Proper way of releasing COM objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728676/proper-way-of-releasing-com-objects)

I followed MS's example on how to wrap `IStream`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> ```
>     public class StreamWrapper : Stream
>     {
>         private IStream m_stream;
>
>        // initialize the wrapper with the COM IStream
>         public StreamWrapper(IStream stream)
>         {
>             if (stream == null)
>             {
>                 throw new ArgumentNullException();
>             }
>
>            m_stream = stream;
>         }
>
>        // .... bunch of other code
>
>        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
>         {
>             if (m_stream != null)
>             {
>                 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_stream); // releases the file
>                 m_stream = null;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Here's a sample.

Follow the link above to see `StreamWrapper`'s implementation...

```
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("mythumbnailer.provider"), Guid("insert-your-guid-here")]
public class QBThumbnailProvider : IThumbnailProvider, IInitializeWithStream
{
    #region IInitializeWithStream

    private StreamWrapper stream{ get; set; }

    public void Initialize(IStream stream, int grfMode)
    {
        // IStream passed to our wrapper which handles our clean up
        this.stream = new StreamWrapper(stream);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IThumbnailProvider

    public void GetThumbnail(int cx, out IntPtr hBitmap, out WTS_ALPHATYPE bitmapType)
    {
        hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        bitmapType = WTS_ALPHATYPE.WTSAT_ARGB;

        try
        {
            //... bunch of other code

            // set the hBitmap somehow
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            using (var image = new Bitmap(stream))
            using (var scaled = new Bitmap(image, cx, cx))
            {
                hBitmap = scaled.GetHbitmap();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        // release the IStream COM object
        stream.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Basically it comes down to two lines of code

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(your_istream); // releases the file
your_istream = null;
```

Side Note

The GDI Bitmap created with `scaled.GetHbitmap();` probably needs to disposed of, but I can't find a way to do it without loosing the created thumbnail.