# VB OLE set object to nothing in C#

Tags: c#, vb6, ole

In VB OLE the object is set to `Nothing`.
I am porting now this code to C#.
Must I set this object in C# to `null` or is this not necessary?

VB

```vb
Set Session oSession = CreateObject("session")
...
Set oSession = Nothing
```

In C#

```cs
var oSession = new Session();
...
oSession = null;
```

Is this the same?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111137/2598770 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111294/2598770 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/2598770

Comment: In general, everything that implements `IDisposable` should be disposed. Other then that, i don't know your code, neither do i know where that`Session` class origins from.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/).

Comment: That's not VB6 code. It would look like `Set oSession = CreateObject("session")` and `Set oSession = Nothing`

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the same?

No.

In VB6 code the session is [destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038890/11683) as soon as you set the variable to `Nothing` (provided that you haven't saved it into another variable too).

In C# the session keeps living and will be released at some point later ([or not](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)).

If you want to destroy the session at that point, and it doesn't implement `IDisposable`, then [force GC to collect it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/11683). Setting the variable to `null` is then not required, provided that you are not referencing that variable later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The Session class is type library class which does not implement IDisposable.
So I conclude Marshall.ReleaseCOMObject is not necessary.